# How can I get detailed info on what Bot Connector Service does to messages sent from registered channels to my endpoint?

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm using MBF for its channel integration with Facebook Messenger.

During development I've been using "ngrok" in order to debug directly sending and receiving messsages from Messenger.
After reaching a completition level, decided to deploy my bot in my work's server setting up an endpoint for channel registration with https as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0).

After deployment, I've been experiencing, what I thought at first, a delay in bot responses as I needed to send the same message or action like 3 times which turns into a terrible UX.

- Moving my bot to azure didn't help.

On a second thought, maybe just messages aren't reaching my endpoint as suggested with what I tried

- Deployed my bot to my local IIS and exposing an endpoint using ngrok monitoring all incoming HTTP Requests.

While interacting with my bot noticed that sometimes it takes like 3 up to 4 messages to reach my endpoint, which didn't happen while debugging. So maybe there might be some issues between my endpoint and Bot Connector Service that I'm missing

Some extra details

- Bot Framework version: 4.4.4
- AppId: dd6bec6b-3177-4930-82ef-45104a947367

Comment: While using ngrok, do you get a response after sending the message just once? Also, just wanted to make sure you followed all the steps to integrate your bot with [messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#exchange-messages-with-the-user) will help you get more idea about what the bot connector service does to the messages sent to the endpoint.

Comment: @ranusharao not everytime, as I mentioned there were some moments where I needed to send the same message like 3 times before it showed me a new HTTP Request in ngrok (which I assume is a request reaching bot connector and then my exposed endpoint). Surely did follow all the steps, managed to solve this issue as it wasn't related to the connector, I'll explain it answering my own question

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this issue wasn't related to Bot Connector.

During my research on bot development on Facebook Messenger, I forgot to delete old applications subscribed to the fan page I was using (reusing same fan page for multiple applications makes weird things apparently).

By deleting old applications and keeping only the one I was using with MBF did the trick. Bot is responding properly now, receiving every message sent.

Comment: Even though this was my mistake, I thought it was better to share it in case someone gets into the same troubles, and as a suggestion to check twice for application subscriptions in facebook's developer platform